# bootstrap - I'm working on bootstrap project and I want to confirm that I'am doing right thing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

this is my second project on bootstrap still I'am not enough familiar with it.

I don't post my codes here and I will give you the url to the testing site. I think it is not a wrong thing to do.

the problem in the site is when I'am re sizing the window width all the text boxes are re sizing like responsive sites. but the thing the height.

my english is not good enough to explain the thing very well. so please try minimizing the browser window. then you  will understand my issue.

and the marquee area also having some issues.

[enter link description here](http://3linksit.com/additionalnet.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having all equal width like your present code

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail mybox1"> Computer Courses </div>
```

You can modify the width when the browser width decreases like

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-sm-4 thumbnail mybox1"> Computer Courses </div>
```

This will result in having 6columns in normal screen and 4columns in smaller screens, u can change the columns by trial and error and check which suits best